# Meteor error: No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor

I am building an app with Meteor for a couple of weeks now, without any problems. Yesterday I didn't had any problems either.
Today I wanted to continue building my app, and the terminal gives me this error every 10 seconds:

```
I20151208-11:19:04.463(1) (android:file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js:25) No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.
```

So I tried running another Meteor project, and got the same error.

I have googled this error, and it says I have to change the config.xml in my project. I dont know where config.xml is located in a Meteor project, but since the error is showing to ALL projects I'm trying to run, I dont think that's the solution.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

EDIT:
I added this line in the `<head>` tag of my Meteor project, and in the `<head>` tag of my .meteor/local/cordova-build/www/index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Also, I added this to my .meteor/local/cordova-build/config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And this to my mobile-config.js file:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

Without success :(

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your index.html header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Comment: Added that line of code in the <head> of my Meteor Project, but its not changing anything.

Comment: Normally I solve this issue by adding this line of code, you can install Cordova Whitelist plugin and add your external links, please check this (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist). Anyway the config.xml file is in the project directory not inside the www directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Restarted my phone, and that solved the problem!